# CSS conditional Comment not working

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements

I have a div that isn't lining up correctly in Chrome, IE and FF. Chrome needs a padding-left:40px; while IE and FF do not. I've been playing with if for a few hours and I know I'm missing something simple.
This is what I've been trying:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link href="non-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I've also tried in the normal style.css:

```
<!--[if !IE]--> 
#lower .expo {padding-left:40px;}
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

or 
     
    #lower .expo {width:400px; padding-top:40px; float:left;}

I also tried this:

```
#lower .expo {width:400px; padding-left:40px; padding-top:40px; float:left;}
<!--[if gt IE 6]> 
#lower .expo {width:400px; padding-top:40px; float:left;}
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Interestingly if I do this:

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]> 
#lower .expo {width:400px; padding-top:40px; float:left;}
<![endif]-->
#lower .expo {width:400px; padding-left:40px; padding-top:40px; float:left;}
```

IE displays correct but not FF or Chrome. Its driving me crazy. I must be missing something simple but I've been looking at it too long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for the sake of your actual error, it lies in how you are doing the comments.  It should be:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link href="non-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

---

For a better way than that, here's what I use:

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6"    lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7"    lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8"    lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9"    lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]>   <html class="ie10"   lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html class="non-ie" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you get to keep the best practice of only using 1 stylesheet.  You simply preface your target with the corresponding IE class you want to hack.

For example:  `.ie6 #target-id`

---

For a more in depth explanation, check out [Paul Irish's](http://paulirish.com/about/) article:

[Conditional stylesheets vs CSS hacks? Answer: Neither!](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

**UPDATE:**

> 2012.01.17: Here is the current iteration that we have in the HTML5 Boilerplate. We actually tried to reduce it down to just a single
>   .oldIE class for IE ≤8 (to use with safe css hacks), but that didn’t
>   fly. Anyway, our current version..
>
> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
> <!--[if IE 7]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
> <!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
> <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class=""><!--<![endif]-->
> ```

Comment: I think your first code block is wrong. It should be `<!--[if !IE ]><!--><link href="non-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: Oh, you meant his error one, gotcha, yea, that was a mistype. Hang on, I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading this javascript file. http://firststepdesign.org/browserselect.js Then link it in your html.

```
<script src="browserselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that go to your css and use these to select specific css for different browsers.

only internet explorer will detect this.

```
.ie .example {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

Only firefox will detect this.

```
.gecko .example {
  background-color: gray
}
```

Only Safari and Chrome will detect this.

```
.webkit .example {
  background-color: black
}
```

Hope this helps if you need to more comment.

Comment: IMHO this solution is not as good as conditional comments, because it requires Javascript to work.

Comment: This is just a simpler way if the above fails I agree with YMMD.

Comment: This javascript file is obsolete.  It won't properly handle newer versions of firefox, etc.  Otherwise it might have value for detecting specific non-IE browsers.